# Need help with trigger to update second field after lookup field updated

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a Custom Object called "Product_Demo_List_*c that has a lookup field (Product*_c) from product which gets Product2.Name.  I also have a text field (Product_Code__c) in my Custom Object that i want to contain the same value from Product2.ProductCode for the record picked.

I can not seem to get this to work and any help would be appreciated.

```
trigger ProductDemoListTrigger on Product_Demo_List__c (before insert, before update){

    for(Product_Demo_List__c pd: trigger.new){    
       for(Product2 p:[select Name,ProductCode from Product2 where Name=:pd.Product__c]){
           pd.Product_Code__c = p.ProductCode;
       }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use a formula field to display the value instead of using a trigger. That way the data is stored on the Product and when updated, you see the updates on all the custom objects.

Comment: I agree with @Daniel, a trigger is not necessary for this.  Formula field will suffice and is native, and simpler.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, a formula fild worked for me.  THANKS MUCH!

Answer (score 3):

Are you certain that the `Product_Demo_List__c.Product__c` field has been populated and matches an actual Product2 Name before the record is inserted? If this isn't the case then the inner SOQL query won't return any Product2 records and the Product_Code__c won't be set.

A Lookup relationship to Product2 might be a better option for handling the relationship. Then, as Daniel Hoechst commented, you could use a formula field to expose the Product Code in you custom object.